# Validate a textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using visual basic 2010 and I have a textbox and I need to validate it to also accept decimal number how can I add the code? I have this code just for integer

```
If Not ( (e.KeyValue >= 48 And e.KeyValue <= 57)  
         OrElse (e.KeyValue >= 96 And e.KeyValue <= 105)   
         OrElse (e.KeyValue = 8) ) Then   
    e.Handled = True  
    MsgBox("Este campo requiere únicamente valores númericos")
    AngulobuzamientoTextBox.Text = vbNullChar


End If
```

Comment: Is this related to VB or VBA? Please tag your question accordingly (VB is not the same as VBA)

Comment: Sorry, is visual basic

Answer (score 3):

Rather than try to validate the characters in the TextBox one at a time as they are typed, I suggest waiting until the user finishes typing and moves focus to another control. Then you can handle the TextBox's Validating event and use `Decimal.TryParse` to validate the text and convert it to a decimal value. If the validation fails, show an error message and set `e.Cancel = True` to prevent the focus moving out of the TextBox.

```
Private number As Decimal

Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Decimal Number")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Joel. As you noticed, I forgot to include the declaration of `number`. However, I intended for it to be declared outside the event handler as (presumably) it would be needed elsewhere, so I have re-edited the answer.

Comment: @GabrielaZeasNuñez If answers your question (and it should), then please take a moment to click the checkmark next to the answer