# Validate textbox in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual basic and I would like to know how to validate a textbox to accept 2 kinds of numbers (integers and decimal numbers)

just I know how to validate for integers:

```
Private Sub NumtelefonoTextBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles NumtelefonoTextBox.KeyDown
        If Not ((e.KeyValue >= 48 And e.KeyValue <= 57) OrElse (e.KeyValue >= 96 And e.KeyValue <= 105) OrElse (e.KeyValue = 8)) Then
            e.Handled = True
            MsgBox("Este campo requiere únicamente valores númericos")
            NumtelefonoTextBox.Text = vbNullChar
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate a textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341055/validate-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

Abandon the Key events and check at event TextChanged if the number IsNummeric():

```
Private Sub txtBoxSample_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBoxSample.TextChanged
    If Not IsNumeric(TxtBoxSample.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Error!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the text changed event handler

```
Private Sub NumtelefonoTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumtelefonoTextBox.TextChanged
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(NumtelefonoTextBox.Text, Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Este campo requiere únicamente valores númericos")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter - please tell me how to improve this response.